# What is M-Base and how do I play it?

Tags: theory, performing, jazz

M-Base was a style of music played by Greg Osby and Steve Coleman.  Steve Coleman over the years has been...cryptic about the principles of M-Base.

What can you tell me about M-Base that will enable me to play in a recognizable M-Base style? Wikipedia is no help in this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

M-Base is:

- Macro - Basic Array of Structured Extemporizations which means...
- Building a common creative musical language on the collective level (macro, basic, array).
- A way of thinking of music as growth through creativity, not a musical style to be set in stone.
- Emphasizes conceptual growth as opposed to technical growth.
- "...A non-western conception of how to use music to express experience. For example, for me the western concepts of time signatures (including so called "common" and "odd time signatures") largely do not exist and have no place in creating music. These concepts come from European art music and the concepts of M-Base are based primarily on music from Afrika and creative music of the Afrikan Diaspora..."

Source: [What is M-Base?](http://www.m-base.com/mbase_explanation.html)